# Dimensionless constant geodesic & Gauss curvature ratio curves

Tags: differential-geometry

I like to define curves with constant  ratio of geodesic curvature $k_g$ to square root of (absolute value of) Gauss curvature $|K|$ not necessarily constant.. if only to visualize them for their bending freedom in isometric deformations.

The defining scalars are derivable from first fundamental form coefficients and Christoffel symbols.

$$ \text{bank}= \dfrac{k_g(s)}{\sqrt{|K(s)|}}$$

Small circles on a sphere or circles defined on a pseudo-sphere are covered by this definition.

Conceptually.. in the physics of circular motion on conical tracks of an automobile or on path of a turning aircraft there occurs such banking of wheels or wings.

The first image below shows constant bank= $ 0.5 $ curves drawn on a sinusoid of revolution with  ***variable*** $ k_g  \text{ and } K $ with respect to arc.

[image]

In this case it so turns out $ (\text{ wavelength, slope, bank =} \lambda , \phi, \pm\; 0.5) $

$$r(s) = a \sin \dfrac{2 \pi z(s)}{\lambda},\; \sqrt{ K} = \dfrac{2 \pi }{\lambda} \cos^2 \phi $$

where the lines run tangentially between two radii.

Would like to know whether such loci are already known. Appreciate links to any references.